# How to list the newest AVRO blobs in a storage account of Event Hub?

Tags: python, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-eventhub

We have an Event Hub instance in Microsoft Azure which captures data in AVRO format into a blob storage account:

[image: event hub]

The blob names are `container1/my-test-namespace/my-test-eventhub` followed by 0, 1, 2 or 3 - and then the date.

I am able to list the blobs using the [ContainerClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.containerclient?view=azure-python) python class:

```
import os, uuid
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient, ContainerClient, __version__

print("Azure Blob storage v" + __version__ + " - List blobs in my-test container1")
connect_str = 'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=...;AccountKey=...;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net'

container_client = ContainerClient.from_connection_string(connect_str, 'container1')
blob_list = container_client.list_blobs()
i = 0
for blob in blob_list:
    print(str(i) + ":\t" + blob.name)
    i = i + 1
    if i >= 10:
        break
```

This works well -

[image: cmd]

However I wonder, how to display the 10 *newest* blobs?

I would like to list the 10 most recent blobs, having ".avro" at the end.

I have searched in the [azure.storage.blob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob?view=azure-python) documentation, but haven't found a way yet.

If you look at the top screenshot, there is a "Modified" column, I wonder if it would be useable from the python script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no `sort` method in azure blob storage sdk.

There're 2 workarounds.

The first one is the you can create an blob triggered azure function, and when a new blob is created in that container, write the related information(like blob_name, creation_time) into a database etc. Then you can query the latest 10 blobs by accessing the database. This is recommended as of now.

The 2nd one is that, you should list all the blobs, then write your own code to sort them by `creation time` property.

Comment: Thanks Ivan. For the 2nd (more straightforward) workaround, what would be the code to access the "creation time" property? I can not find it yet

Comment: @AlexanderFarber, it's just like that you fetch the blob name via `blob.name`, directly use `blob.creation_time`.

Comment: What about the [BlobQueryReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.blobqueryreader?view=azure-python), can't a query retrieve 10 recent blobs ending with ".avro"?

Comment: @AlexanderFarber, it doesn't have the sort-like parameter, so you cannot.